# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el valor de un ion-option a un provider en ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación que desde un ion-option me devuelva el valor seleccionado a un provider, para aplicarlo a la ruta de acceso a un archivo json del tipo:

midominio/"valor seleccionado"/archivo.json

Me funciona todo excepto esto, ya que no soy capaz de devolver el {{valor seleccionado}} a mi provider para darle la ruta al json. Se que funciona porque puedo escribir la ruta completa en el archivo html.

Dado que soy muy neófito en esto os agradecería una pequeña ayuda.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Tengo resuelto un caso similar con la siguiente estructura:
Con esto podrás recuperar el valor seleccionado, llamar a la función "enviarAProvider()" y ahí ya lo que consideres.

```html
<ion-select name="nombre" [(ngModel)]="miVariable" okText="Ok" cancelText="Cancelar">
  <ion-option (click)="enviarAProvider()" *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o.valor">{{o.descripcion}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

```ts
miVariable:string;
enviarAProvider(){
  '...midominio/'+this.miVariable+'/archivo.json...'
}
```